# Nexus 7 is stuck in reboot loop after full discharge

Tags: nexus-7, boot-loop

I have a few day old Nexus 7 tablet, unrooted, bootloader still locked, and otherwise in factory condition. This morning, it ran its charge out. When I plugged in it, this happens:

1. Google Logo appears.
2. Nexus Logo appears.
3. Lock screen which shows charging: 0%.
4. White screen, device powers off.
5. Repeat.

What is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some devices (I don't know about the Nexus 7, but I think it will be about the same) only charge when they have still a little charge left on their battery, because - believe it or not - charging happens electronically. So it can be that your device has absolutely no juice left to run. An example of such a device is the BlackBerry PlayBook (not Android) where this trick works when your tablet doesn't want to boot.

But there is a simple solution for that, which can take some time. Try to keep your device awake for as long as possible, even if that means you have to restart it a couple of times. Of course you do this while your charger is connected. After you have restarted it a couple of times, it should normally boot up. I expect it will take about 7 or 8 boots for the battery to be charged at minimum level again. After that, make sure you keep the device connected long enough so the battery is fully charged (have a look in your user manual how long it is recommended, most tablets need about 8 hours).

**Another option** is that your device just needs a little more juice to start. In that case you should leave it plugged in for some time (I recommend at least an hour) before booting.

tl;dr: Two options you could try: 1) Just keep restarting it, after a while it will start as normal. Recharge the battery for a long time (probably around 8 hours). 2) Leave it plugged in for a long time before restarting

Answer (score 5):

If you've just plugged it in to the charger, leave it a while before you try to turn it on.  The boot sequence uses power faster than USB can provide it, so you will need a little juice in the battery in order for it to boot up all the way.

Comment: There are a few 2A power adapters out there that should provide enough current for the device to complete the boot process even if the battery is empty.