# Nexus7 Stuck in Reboot Following Full Discharge

Tags: battery, charging, nexus-7, boot-loop

I am experiencing the same symptoms as described in the following:

" [Nexus 7 is stuck in reboot loop after full discharge](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36220/nexus-7-is-stuck-in-reboot-loop-after-full-discharge) "

My Nexus 7 is full discharged.   I have it connected to Factory AC-to-USB adapter.   It cycles through boot up, sounds a tone ... stays on perhaps for 10-20 seconds ... long enough to display "0% Charging" ... and then powers itself down, again with another tone.    On some instances when it powers down the screen display shows 'static' with accompanying white noise sound, like an old television set.

I've had it plugged in for over 4 hours ... and its cycled probably 2-3 dozen times.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you get it to boot into recovery mode? Press and hold Power until the device powers on, then immediately press and hold Volume Down (while still pressing Power). You will see the word Start with an arrow drawn around it. When in that mode, will it accept a charge?

Comment: following those steps gets the unit into 'Safe Mode' ... but it powers down in about the same amount of time.

Comment: Do you have it plugged in to AC to charge, or a USB port? The latter isn't enough to effectively charge the Nexus 7 (or any tablet, really).

Comment: After perhaps another 90 minutes of continued cycles ... the battery charging icon finally appeared ... and after another handful of cycles the power was a 2%, sufficient enough to keep it running while charging.    So now the Nexus7 is charging up fine.   (Won't let it fully discharge again.)